# Replace files in sub folders with gulp / imagemin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I've folder structure as

```
assets/images/foo/abc.jpg
assets/images/bar/def.jpg 
..
```

I want to **imagemin** them and place the images in the same sub folders, with gulp, how to do?

```
var paths = {
    images: 'assets/images/**/*'
};

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.images)
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(???));
});
```

What should I put in the `gulp.dest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this future recipe :

https://github.com/arvindr21/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/maintain-directory-structure-while-globbing.md

> If you want to maintain the structure, you need to pass {base: '.'} to gulp.src().